# It there a way to do edge detection on plane?

Tags: node-editor

I know if I have a volume I can do bevel, which gives me edges of each plane. However I only have a plane, and I need to mark the edge of it.

Something like https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/xBcbbc/ would be great.

And I am using cycles

Comment: yes, there is a node for that. you can download it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21G2l2EYhLY

Comment: @Chris ... that looks to me as if it's AO and noise - based, so wouldn't work on a plane?

Comment: @RobinBetts: AO? what's that? and yes, your are right, it does not work on a plane, i just tried it. Maybe Awoo is happy if he can use it and he just has to tap on his plane, press tab, press 'E' and move his mouse just a little bit up, click on mouse, press tab again and the it works on his "plane" ;D ...and i wonder...it works on older versions of Blender, but not in 3.0.0alpha? do you have an idea why? and by the way...noise works on a plane!? just tried it out. or what do you mean?

Comment: Hi @Chris. Ambient Occlusion, firing a cluster of rays in the hemisphere of  directions around the normal of  the shading point, and seeing whether a hit is scored. Simple plane, no hits, no score. Noise mask to modulate the resulting shading? I don't know.. but the scale of that could be 'frequency' the video refers to.

Comment: @RobinBetts: Thank you! i thought of Add-on ;) Learnt again and again from you!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7):

I believe this isn't possible at present without adding additional geometry to indicate the "edgeiness". However, this can be achieved (in a slightly "hacky" way) if you have a single face by way of the 'inset face' operation.

For example, consider the following mesh :

[image: original planar face]

In edit mode, select the face and press <kbd>I</kbd> to start the inset operation then move the cursor to size the inset. If you need to inset further than the geometry allows (concave faces can result in overlapping edges) then you can Scale or manually manipulate the vertices to get the desired shape - the 'fade' will be along the extent of the inset face :

[image: inset edge]

Then all that is required is to allocate the gradient by either using Vertex Colors or UV coordinates. For example, in the UV editor you can select all the 'Inner' vertices and move those to the top edge of the UV map, then select all the 'Outer' vertices and move those to the bottom edge of the UV map and then use the Y element of the UV map to give your edge gradient :

[image: UV allocate inner and outer]

Then you can simply use the UV 'V' coordinate ('Y' from the Separate XYZ) to represent the distance from the edge :

[image: result]

Comment: Damn. That’s genius.