# Gradient texture around a low poly plain! object

Tags: texturing

Can you tell me if it is possible to make a texture gradient around a low poly plain (without using the height difference) object (from sides or UV sides) in shading mode?
Something like on this pictures?

[image: gradient example]

Additional:

- For EEVEE
- In material shading mode (using nodes)
- Vertex Color (Low poly) gives square looking gradient - not so good
- The side with this gradient must be plain or close to plain (Use the height of one of the coordinates will not work)

Comment: are you in Eevee or Cycles? It's not possible in Eevee as far as I know, except manually with vertex colors for example

Comment: Add answers in "Additionals"

Comment: @vklidu: whom do you mean? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It is quite hard to call this answer ... it works in some way, but it requires several steps. One step is based on Markus's [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221735/it-there-a-way-to-do-edge-detection-on-plane) with adjusted UVmap, than Bake with Cycles and Blur that by nodes ... if there would be space for joking - good news: it is one material :)*

*In general I wanted to use UV vectors converted into BW image and distort with Image Blur node group ... I'm not able to find a way combine Vector with color data of UV ... so if someone is able to figure out so we can skip baking ...*

---

First create two UVmaps:

- UVmap
- UVmap than select border vertices scale to 0 and move them into one corner, Invert Select and Scale to 0 and move vertices into oposit corner

[image]

Than create this node-tree material ... add a new Image node (with top view UVmap node) and keep selected so the Emit pass is baked into this texture.

[image]

Last step plug Image node to output and play with Factor of Image Blur node group.

[image]
[image]

Note: I didn't tested but since it use baked texture vertex color would work in the same way.

[image]

Open .blend hit Bake and reconnect Image texture node to Output

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ... any thoughts how to distort ColorRamp output by NodeGroup?  Or any other thoughts how to math border from UV ... without creating this UV hack? :)

Comment: one of my thoughts was solidify, smooth shading, using normals, but the result was mediocre. Here's a result I got with the UV technique in the duplicate: https://i.imgur.com/VJlbx81.gif I'm using subdivision (simple) as well as a simple node setup: https://i.imgur.com/S7q0rKv.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ... Looks good :) seems to be useful as answer (extension of existed) ...

Comment: @vklidu Very difficult Bake :) One houre I tried all till I recive your result. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexLovsky What make it so difficult? Probably should be mentioned in the answer ... Have you tried Markus's simpler tech with Subdiv Modifier? Easier to apply with decent result (grid still noticeable, but probably not an issue for you?) ...